# ImageIcon how to get filepath of image for use in java?

Tags: java, image, swing, filepath

I am trying to use `ImageIcon` with Java Swing in order to power a simple `Java` game. I would like understand how to call a relative filepath from the eclipse workspace inside a project folder? What is the code that can be used to implement the relative filepath in eclipse for an image resource?

Comment: I hope this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) might be of some help in the given direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
getClass().getResource()
```

Something like this:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images.jpg")));
```

If `images` is in your project folder.